# Canon PIXMA MG3029

Tags: drivers, printing

I had Solus installed and installed my newly purchased Canon PIXMA MG3029 printer with the MG3000 series driver Ubuntu system recommended.  The power light flashed when you sent a job to the printer, but nothing ever came out.  I installed then Ubuntu 17.04 standard and reinstalled the printer, hiwever with the same result as Solus.  Any suggestions or tricks you may have to have me become "printer friendly"?

Comment: This is a comprehensive guide: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/18

Answer (score 1):

so if you were to install the drivers that Canon supply, you would start here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100839901.html and click to download and please SAVE what will be cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz

I would suggest at this stage opening your PRINTERS folder and deleting any icons there; as you say they do not work ...

It should end up in your Downloads folder by default. Open a terminal and paste in one by one the commands below; right-click on the text prompt in the terminal to see the PASTE option ..

`cd Downloads`

`tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz`

`cd cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb`

`./install.sh` and that will run the install script and should set up a printer driver for you;

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2017/10/27/how-to-install-canon-mg3010-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-step-by-step/) worked for me.  After installing some libraries, it points to [this Canon site](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg3050.html?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)) for package downloading.  I used the `Debian` package and it self installed and was up and running immediately.